# Angular 2 RC1 tests "Failed: No provider for TestComponentBuilder!"

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I think I have a reasonable configuration:

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {

var dist = "dist/";
var src = "src/";

config.set({
    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
        // System.js for module loading
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

        // Polyfills for older browsers
        'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js',

        // Reflect and Zone.js
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

        // RxJs.
        { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
        { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

        // Angular 2 itself and the testing library
        { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
        { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

        'karma-test-shim.js',

        // Widget's bundles
        { pattern: dist + 'widget-ui.min.css', included: true, watched: true },
        { pattern: 'node_modules/widget-angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },

        // Application bundles
        { pattern: dist + 'src/lib.bundle.js', included: true, watched: true },
        { pattern: dist + 'src/core.bundle.js', included: true, watched: true },
        { pattern: dist + 'src/about.bundle.js', included: true, watched: true },
        { pattern: dist + 'src/admin.bundle.js', included: true, watched: true },
        { pattern: 'src/test.bundle.js', included: true, watched: true },

        // Paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
        { pattern: src + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: true }
    ],

    // proxied base paths
    proxies: {
        // Required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
        '/dist/src/': '/base/dist/src/'
    },

    exclude: [src + 'jspm_packages/**/*.ts'],

    reporters: ['progress'],

    plugins: [
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-chrome-launcher'
    ],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG, // was LOG_INFO

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    singleRun: false
    })
};
```

karma-test-shim.js

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

__karma__.loaded = function () {

};

function isTestSpecFile(path) {
    return path.slice(-7) == 'spec.ts';
}

function extractModuleName(path) {
    return path.replace("/base/src/", "");
}

var allTestSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(isTestSpecFile);

// Load our SystemJS configuration.

var packages = {
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

// Add angular packages to SystemJS config
[
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    '@angular/upgrade'
].forEach(function (name) { packages[name] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }; });

System.config({
    baseURL: '/base',
    map: {
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
        '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular'
    },
    packages: packages
});

Promise.all([
            System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
            System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing/browser')
        ])
.then(function(modules) {
    var testing = modules[0];
    var testingBrowser = modules[1];

    testing.setBaseTestProviders(
        testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
        testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
})

    .then(function () {
        // Finally, load all spec modules.
        // This will run the tests directly.
        return Promise.all(
            allTestSpecFiles.map(extractModuleName).map(function (moduleName) {
                return System.import(moduleName);
            }));
    })
.then(function() { __karma__.start(); }, function(error) { __karma__.error(error.stack || error); });
```

Finally the test itself:

```
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {
    beforeEach,
    beforeEachProviders,
    describe,
    expect,
    it,
    inject,
    async
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {TestComponentBuilder, ComponentFixture} from '@angular/compiler/testing';

import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/Rx'; // load the full rxjs

import { SimpleUserListComponent } from '../../admin/components/simple-user-list.component';
import { SimpleUserService } from "../../core/services/simple-user.service";
import { User } from "../../core/models/user";

@Injectable()
class MockUserService {
    public getUsers() {
        return Promise.resolve(<User[]>[{ "id": "999", "username": "ABC" }, { "id": "998", "username": "DEF" }]);
    }
}

/// Delete this
describe('Smoke test', () => {
    it('should run a passing test', () => {
        expect(true).toEqual(true, 'should pass');
    });
});

describe('SimpleUserListComponent with new', function () {
    it('should instantiate component', () => {
        expect(new SimpleUserListComponent()).toBeDefined('Whoopie!');
    });
});


describe('SimpleUserListComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(async(inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
        return tcb
            .overrideProviders(SimpleUserListComponent, [{provide: SimpleUserService, useClass: MockUserService}])
            .createAsync(SimpleUserListComponent)
            .then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture) => {
                this.listComponentFixture = componentFixture;
                const element = this.listComponentFixture.nativeElement;
                this.listComponentFixture.detectChanges();
            });
    })));

    it('should render list', (done) => {
        const element = this.listComponentFixture.nativeElement;
        this.listComponentFixture.detectChanges();

        var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
            if (element.querySelectorAll('li').length == 2) {
                expect(element.querySelectorAll('li').length).toBe(2);
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
            done(); // call this to finish off the it block
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

My non-async tests work correctly.

But as soon as I try an async test setup, it fails with:

```
Failed: No provider for TestComponentBuilder!
    Error: DI Exception
        at NoProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (src/test.bundle.js:21783:21)
        at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (src/test.bundle.js:19605:14)
        at new NoProviderError (src/test.bundle.js:19629:14)
        at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (src/test.bundle.js:19026:17)
        at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (src/test.bundle.js:19050:23)
        at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (src/test.bundle.js:19019:23)
        at ReflectiveInjector_.get (src/test.bundle.js:18832:21)
        at src/test.bundle.js:14453:32
...
```

What am I missing?